# How can I find out what clients aredoing with my samba server

Tags: samba, client

I have a samba server in my Ubuntu system and I want to know what clients are doing. I want to see:

- folders visited by clients even if they are disconnected.
- files downloaded by clients.
- IP addresses of clients.